# How do you print exported module constants in Perl?

Tags: perl, constants

I want to define some constants in one package and then use them in another package, but I don't seem to be doing this right! At first shot I was getting

> Bareword "FAVORITE_COLOR" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at ...

I guess it was because I wasn't using the base path for my package in the lib() function,

Module
**My/Colors.pm**

```
package My::Colors;

BEGIN {
  use Exporter;
  our($VERSION, @ISA, @EXPORT, @EXPORT_OK, %EXPORT_TAGS);
  $VERSION     = 1.00;
  @ISA         = qw(Exporter);
  @EXPORT      = qw(  );
  @EXPORT_OK   = qw( FAVORITE_COLOR DISLIKED_COLOR );  
  %EXPORT_TAGS = ( 'all' => [ @EXPORT, @EXPORT_OK ], 'const' => [ 'FAVORITE_COLOR', 'DISLIKED_COLOR'] ); 

}
our @EXPORT_OK;

use lib qw( /home/dev );

use Carp;


use constant {     
  DISLIKED_COLOR => "green",
  FAVORITE_COLOR => "red"
};

sub new {
 my($class, %args) = @_;
 my $self = bless({}, $class);
 my $target = exists $args{target} ? $args{target} : "new";
 $self->{target} = $target;
 return $self;
}


1;
```

Module that includes exported constants
**color_driver.plx**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use warnings;
use strict;
use diagnostics;

use lib qw( /home/dev/My );
use Colors;
use Colors qw(:const);


sub main{
  my $color = new Colors;
  print "Color is",FAVORITE_COLOR;

}

main();
```

any idea what I'm doing wrong?

When I remove strict the constant doesnt translate to its value =/

**Updated**
Unfortunately now perl is complaining that it can't find new sub

> Can't locate object method "new" via package "Colors" (perhaps you
>   forgot to
>           load "Colors"?) at color_driver.plx line 15 (#1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the module:

```
package My::Colors;
```

In the script:

```
use lib qw( /home/dev/My );
use Colors qw(:const);

my $color = new Colors;
```

Either change those lines of the module to

```
package Colors;
```

or change those lines of the script to

```
use lib qw( /home/dev );
use My::Colors qw(:const);

my $color = new My::Colors;
```

---

```
use Colors qw( :const );
```

is almost identical to

```
BEGIN {
    require Colors;
    Colors->import(qw( :const ));
}
```

You are telling Perl to look in the `Colors` package/namespace for `import` (and `new`), but the module populates the package/namespace `My::Colors`.

Comment: woo that kind of worked -- new still isnt working, but when I took the new call out the other constants worked. But if I put the right path in the lib() function why should I have to include the full Package path? I'd like to just do use Colors qw(:const)

Comment: @codeninja, There was no `new` in what you had posted at the time. Anyway, updated.

Comment: --- oic!!! the package has to coordinate with the lib() too! thank you ^_^ -- sorry I was in the middle of updating and testing when you were commenting -- I tried to sync everything up and update the question at the same time -- so dont be mad! If you could fix that little down vote there I think we can both be happy! thank you again!

Comment: @codeninja, Now that we can see the whole picture, I've added a bit of explanation.